# I can't figure out how to put this in the first line

Tags: c

I can't figure out how to get the input to show-up after Enter a Character. Would appreciate if someone can help me figureout how.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

const int ESC = 27;

char change_case(char cIn);
int main() {
   
    char ch;
    do {
        printf("Enter a character: \n");
        ch = _getch();
        if (ch == 27)
            break;
        printf("Changed Character: %c \n\n", change_case(ch));
    } while (1);

}

char change_case(char cIn) {
    if (cIn >= 'a' && cIn <= 'z')
        return cIn - 32;
    else if (cIn >= 'A' && cIn <= 'Z')
        return cIn + 32;
    printf("\nTHAT IS NOT A LETTER!\n");
    return cIn;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_getch()/getch()` does not echo the keyboard input. Use `_getche()` instead - it does echo input.